# Can we use Couchbase as the message store for Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, couchbase, spring-integration-dsl

We are implementing Spring Integration aggregator and using JDBC message data store. In our environment we have Couchbase and Oracle DB. I don't want to use Oracle DB, can we use couchbase as the message store.
If yes, can you please suggest the approach.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [MessageStore](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/store/MessageStore.html) strategy that you would need to implement and then configure as any other message store in your Spring Integration components that required it. Here is a [bit more info](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/src/reference/asciidoc/message-store.adoc).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As per the instruction messagestore supports the following  JDBCMessageStore, Redis MessageSTore, Mongo MessageStore, Gemfire MessageStore

Comment: You listed current implementation of MessageStore. there is about 100+ more user implemented in their environment . So, all I am saying is that you should implement your own message store for Couchbase and it will work seamlessly with SI.